# Stop auto start of Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I've a countdown timer. In the end of 60 secs I started a new activity. It works fine. But if I press home button or back button before the countdown timer ends, after that particular time the activity starts automatically even if I'm in home screen. I finished the activity using this.finish(); But still doesn't work. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: in `OnPause` use `youtTimer.cancel();`

Comment: cancel timer onPause() in first activity.

Comment: only on onPause() or onDestroy() also??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the OnPause event of the activity. When the activity is sent to back, finish it.

```
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            timer.cancel();
            this.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle your timer in `onPause()/onResume()` or `onDestroy()` of your activity according to your requirement.

eg. If you want to simply stop the timer use:

`timer.cancel()` in `onDestroy()`

something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
timer.cancel();
super.onDestroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the home and back button in your code, because the background thread keeps on running and so your activity starts even if you are on home screen.
I am giving you this code for home button disable for your activity.

```
 @Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
 this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
 super.onAttachedToWindow();
 }
```

This will disable your Home button while you are on that activity.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ya.. This is also an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When user pressed home or back button the timer thread is running in background so you have to Override the onDestroy() method and stop the timer in it.